# How do I tell the ASP.Net publish wizard to use a proper URL for browsing locally

Tags: asp.net

I am newer to ASP.Net.  I am normally a desktop application developer creating content for internal company consumption.

I have been fighting Visual Studio for a couple of days now to publish a basic webapplication.  I am using VS Comm 2019, C#.Net and targeting .Net 4.7.2  (This is Windows only!)

I am really close to getting this thing to work and I think I need SO to get me across the finish line.

- I do not have a DefaultWebSite in IIS.  I deleted it using advise from SO.

I was able to publish with this settings

server: localhost
sitename: WebApp01
destination url: webapp01.net
user name/pwd: both are correct
[image: publish settings]

I created a website in IIS with these settings:
[image: IIS website]

Publishing in Visual Studio with web publish seems to work well.
After I publish the site comes up like this
[image]

I know that is an invalid url.  What can I do to get a proper local site up and running so I may continue my work?  Thanks in advance!  Please ask for more details.  As a newer ASP.Net I am sure I forgot something and don't mean to poke any bears out there.

Comment: did the default web site work before you deleted it? I would have published to a different folder. And from iis can you launch the site on that server (from the IIS panel - the browse option on the right side). Also, try using IP for site - and not a name - they often have difficulty being registered on your internal network

Comment: I deleted the default site beforehand but on good SO advice.  Can you please be a little more specific on a next step?  For example can you look at my images and suggest edits for any of the text boxes and the values that go in it?  If all else fails the bookstore has a book on IIS10.

Comment: The issue was not that you deleted, but did the IIS site work before you deleted it? I mean if that known working site never worked in the first place then little sense to try publishing your site then, right? As noted I would try setting up using IP address - in fact I use ip address on my test server running iis. However as noted, if that default site never worked, then your site probably not going to either. And I used folder publish to a local folder. Then open the folder and copy paste everything over the working default site. But then again we back to if the default site was working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to try to answer my question as best as possible.

The secret sauce is definitely shared between the ASP.Net C# solution and a 'website' in IIS.  I will post pictures for my answers and a picture of publishing.

Ensure proper IIS Windows features for ASP.NET C# dynamic pages

[image: IIS Features]My Application is named 'WebFoo'

[image: Visual Studio Web Deploy Publish Settings]

[image: Additional Publish Settings]

[image: Andy added as an application pool]

[image: Andy applications]

[image: Andy website in IIS]

[image: Andy Application]

[image: Andy Application published - The crowd goes wild!!!!!]

Comment: Most credit goes to the authors of Murach's ASP.NET 4.6 w/ C# 2015.  They are Mary Delamater and Anne Boehm.  Mr. Kallal's tips were very informative and helped open the way for the aha moment.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it will work locally without updating hosts file.

1. Go to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
2. Open 'hosts' file as Administrator
3. Add the following line to the bottom of the file:

   127.0.0.1 webapp01.net
4. Give it a couple of minutes and try reloading your browser tab once again.

Comment: The hairs on the back of my neck start to tingle when thinking of manipulating the hosts file to do something.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it not clear if when you publish, that you have the web site setup correctly (you have to install some publishing software into that web server to work).

So, what I would do is simply publish your web site to a local folder.

Say like this:

[image]

So, we use file publish - that way we eliminate the 100 or more issues of having setup the web server to accept the publishing system (there is a lot of gears and leavers so to speak to set that up. This way, we publish local - no ftp, no logon, no passwords to connect etc. And NO NEED for even if the web server is up and running).

Ok so in above, "web" folder, we will have what amounts to the required working web site. At that point, you can FTP, copy to a jump drive or whatever. We simple now need to COPY this folder to the server.

So, on the server, we have this folder:

[image]

So, just copy/move/get the web folder from your local computer to the above default web site.

once you done that, then you can config, or even start up that web site from IIS.

eg this:

[image]

In fact, even BEFORE you start up the site, why not choose this option:

[image]

That option (explore) will simply open up the folder on the server WHERE that site resides. Maybe your config different. Maybe the location is on a different drive (drive d:). Don't really know, don't care. The simple matter is you want to 100%, and in fact 200% be sure you open  up the correct folder. Since that folder is where you copy your local published web folder to (actually the files in side that folder - you copy to the folder that the web site is running).

Next up:
As noted, it not clear due to fire wall issues, network settings, are you on a domain (and the 100+ more possible issues to be aware of), then as I noted, I strong, but STRONG suggest you get this up and working by IP address. The only exception to this rule is if you already say have a URL and a hosting mapping setup (say for a production web server that say outside users will be using). But so far, sounds like this is internal for testing.

Ok, now you need the IP of that server this site is running on. One the other hand, IIS is quite cool, in that you can use + assign a DIFFERENT IP address for the web site - and you can do this without say adding a extra network card. Don't know if the web site is assigned a IP address, or is fixed????

anyway, assuming you copied the files from your local "file" web publish, then next is to setup the bindings, or at least check them.

eg this:

so, FIRST click on your site (highlight) - left side, and then on right side select bindings:

[image]

And now you can enter your URL, but as noted, doubt you have names resolution working, but as noted, at least test/try IP address.

eg:

[image]

So, set the site to a IP address You can often leave this blank. But at least check this.

And while most servers have their browser locked down (can't run JavaScript etc.), you can at least click on this to launch the site - see if it at least launches to main page:

[image]

So, above should only take a minute or two to test and try.

As noted, if you using a file publish, then you should stop the web site, or at the very least re-start the web site from IIS if you use file publishing, but at least a file copy is quite a fail safe approach to taking your first baby steps until over time you say or attempt to use publishing directly to the site from Visual Studio.

I in fact, still use the above simple file publish - even for FTP, since then I can use any FTP software, and all we are doing is copy some files from a folder local to the folder on the server that IIS is pointing to for that given site.

Comment: Albert D. Kallal - This is a very rich response that I am still processing.  I will need at least a day before I can really comment on the many things you covered.  FWIW - I purchased a IIS 10: Web Aoos, Security & Maintenance (Kindle version).  At least I will have something to read over the next 2 days of high level meetings at work.

Comment: Albert D. Kallal - I did get my publish to IIS to work on a localhost without any hosts trickery

Comment: Update - I got it to publish and work with a static file as my 'default.html'.  The project is correctly published to my local IIS.    I am now trying to solve the issue with dynamic content not rendering due to some MIME configuration issue in my project.

Comment: Yes, there can be a lot of setup and configuration of a web server - even the default page setting. In fact, when I do my file publish, I OFTEN delete the web config file before I copy over to the IIS site (since I often tweaked and changed things on the web server, and I don't want to lose those changes. While Visual Studio has "somehow" managed to give a great developer experience to build a web site, deployment to a production version of IIS will often require some additonal work. - it is called a learning curve.

Comment: I've run into big issues publishing to local folders.  IIS is complaining about Roslyn.  There are some MIME issues that just prevent a vanilla project to publish with this method.  I'd try to use it for publishing to a server via a file share if I could get past that problem.

Comment: Well, for a web site, this would be true. For a web site application, its less of a issue. As noted, I now often dump the app_code folder (since that is compiled by IIS). I simply create a folder called MyCode, and each class (or module) I place in that folder, you have to right click on that class and change the build action from nothing to compile. with a web site app, then the code will be compiled by VS, and not IIS, and hence the roslyn issue goes away. But yes, you are correct, and I had to deal with some code not compiling by IIS correctly, but not using app_code was one workaround.